# How to write a loop-free code to find the max in each region?

Tags: python, arrays, max

I have a vector which specifies a number of regions over `1` to `N`. For example, if

```
  A = [1,2,3,6,7,9,10]
```

Then the regions are [1,3], [6,7], [9,10] defined over interval `[1,10]` with `N=10`. I have another vector with length `N` that contains a set of positive and negative numbers:

```
 x = [0.8,0.1,1,-1,-2,-0.76,0.1,0.2,0.9,0.6]
```

I want to find the maximum value of `x` in each region. In this example, the result is:

```
 y = [1,0.1,0.9]
 y_locs = [3,7,9]
```

It is possible to compute the max in each region by first obtaining regions from `A` and then using a for loop to find the max in each region. Is there a loop-free way to do that?

Comment: Python or MATLAB? Please tag only one language. Also, the [find] tag pop-up specifically states "do not use this tag", so please don't use that tag.

Comment: Your regions don't match up with the values in `A`

Answer (score 0):

You could slice your array and use the built in `max()` function. Something like:

```
x = [0.8, 0.1, 1, -1, -2, -0.76, 0.1, 0.2, 0.9, 0.6]

# each tuple contains (start_index, length, maximum_value)
max_list = [(0, 3, max(x[0:3])), (5, 2, max(x[5:7])), (8, 2, max(x[8:]))]
locations_list = [max_list[i][0] + x[max_list[i][0]:max_list[i][0] + max_list[i][1]].index(max_list[i][2]) + 1 for i in range(len(max_list))]
print(max_list)
print(locations_list)
```

Yields:

```
[(0, 3, 1), (5, 2, 0.1), (8, 2, 0.9)]
[3, 7, 9]
```

Notes:

- I did use a for loop to iterate each section, but you could expand this by hand into three separate lines that do not have a for loop (this would become very tedious for large data though)
- I do not know the internals of `max()` and it may use a for loop that is hidden.